# Triangle Properties application

Tags: triangles

In a triangle ABC, AD is the altitude from A. Given b>c, $\angle C = {23^o}$,$AD = \frac{{abc}}{{{b^2} - {c^2}}}$. Then  $\angle B = \_\_\_{\_^o}$

My approach is as follow

$\frac{a}{{\sin A}} = \frac{b}{{\sin B}} = \frac{c}{{\sin C}} = 2R$

$AD = \frac{{8{R^3}sinA\sin B\sin C}}{{4{R^2}{{\sin }^2}B - 4{R^2}{{\sin }^2}C}} = \frac{{2RsinA\sin B\sin C}}{{\sin \left( {B - C} \right)\sin \left( {B + C} \right)}} = \frac{{2R\sin B\sin C}}{{\sin \left( {B - C} \right)}}$

How do I approach from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the extended law of sines and the area of a triangle in terms of sides and circumradius formulae.

$$\bigtriangleup=\frac{1}{2}a\cdot AD \implies AD= \frac{2\triangle}{a} = \frac{{abc}}{{{b^2} - {c^2}}}=\frac{4R \bigtriangleup}{{b^2} - {c^2}}$$

$$\implies 2Ra={b^2} - {c^2}$$
$$\implies 2R(2R\cdot \sin(A))=(2R\cdot \sin(B))^2 - {(2R\cdot \sin(C))}^2$$
$$\implies \sin(A)=\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)$$

Can you take it from here?

> $$B=C+90°$$

There is also another version of this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653634/find-angle-b-if-ad-fracabcb2-c2?noredirect=1).

Comment: Thanks for the edit cosmo5.